# Versões antigas com puppet

Tags: vagrant

Estou aprendendo Vagrant e Puppet e quero saber se possível instalar versões antigas do PHP, MySQL, Apache utilizando o puppet? Se sim, como fazer?

Ex: PHP 5.4.9, 5.5
Mysql 5.5.27, 5.6

Answer (score 2):

Você pode especificar uma versão:

```
package { 'php' :
  ensure => '5.2' ,
}
```

Mas lembre que se a versão necessária do pacote (RPM, deb, etc) não estiver disponível no seu repositório padrão, você terá que seguir por um desses caminhos:

- Encontrar um repositório alternativo que tem o pacote na versão que você precisa e adicioná-lo a lista de repositórios.
- Configurar seu próprio repositório que contém esse pacote
- Instalar diretamente, especificando o caminho para o pacote, conforme explicado a seguir.

Poderia ser assim:

```
package { 'php' : 
    ensure => '5.2' , 
    source => '/caminho/para/o/php-5.2.rpm' , 
}
```

Resposta tirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616432/1706351)

Comment: O que seria esse "php-5.2.rpm" ?

Comment: serve o caminho para o tar.gz ?

Comment: .rpm é o pacote da distribuição que você esta usando.  No caso, poderia ser o Fedora. Você está usando o Ubuntu?

Comment: Sim, utilizo o ubuntu 13.04 .. onde acho esses pacotes ? preciso das versões do mysql tbm

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com as versões dos pacotes que você precisa, para que possamos tentar te ajudar.